# Call a function inside a if condition

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi guys i am trying to move my if condition code inside another new function and i would like to call that in my another function how can i do that

Here is my if condition :

```
if (self::GRID_LIST_STATUS_AGENDA === $gridType) {
            // Personal agenda sortation of statuses
            unset($finalFilters['statusId']['distinct']);
            $finalFilters['statusId']['values'] = [
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_REPLY_RELATION => 'relation reply',
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_REMINDER => 'followup',
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_NEW => 'new',
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_IN_PROGRESS => 'in progress',
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_REOPEN => 'reopened',
            ];
        }
```

Here is the new function that  i want to move

```
/**
     * Get personal agenda sortation statuses
     */
    public function personalAgendaSortationStatuses()
    {

    }
```

Can anyone help me how can i do that

Comment: yes its working..thank you thanks a lot

Comment: from the first function you returned some data to second function and now it's up-to-you that what you want to do with that data. if you want to return then use return , if you want to print print there. completely your choice as well as depended on what the second function intended to do.

Comment: i have already used return $finalFilters; in my  old function now we have used same in our current function so can i remove that in my old fucntion? it wont make any problem to my old fucntion rite?

Comment: No you can't. leave it in older one and remove it from second-one

Comment: okay can one function have two return statements, because in my old function i have already used return $finalFilters; and now i want to use return $statuses too.. if i didnt use return for $statuses  the result is not coming exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: one function cannot have  2 returns. you can use array to return multiple data at a time from one function

Comment: okay sure..thank you for your help

Comment: Okay i am going to post question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change function code like below:-

```
public function personalAgendaSortationStatuses($gridType,$finalFilters) //pass parameter
    {
        if (self::GRID_LIST_STATUS_AGENDA === $gridType) {
            // Personal agenda sortation of statuses
            unset($finalFilters['statusId']['distinct']);
            $finalFilters['statusId']['values'] = [
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_REPLY_RELATION => 'relation reply',
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_REMINDER => 'followup',
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_NEW => 'new',
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_IN_PROGRESS => 'in progress',
                BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::STATUS_REOPEN => 'reopened',
            ];
            return $finalFilters;
        }
    }
```

And call it in another function like this:-

```
$statuses = $this->personalAgendaSortationStatuses(self::GRID_LIST_STATUS_AGENDA,$finalFilters);//send second parameter too
```